# PDF Handler Problem with Chrome & Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, google-chrome, handler

Well I solved the problem of running out of memory when accessing the PDF files, but now it seems that when I try to access big files via Chrome or Firefox I get gibberish. It doesn't open Adobe, it just display it as a page with millions of characters. Im using the code below to get it to the user, any ideas on why it would be doing this?

```
case "PDF":
     context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + asset.A_Name);
}

context.Response.BinaryWrite(content);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a content length header to the response. Its a problem with IIS chunked encoding. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419281/content-length-header-versus-chunked-encoding).

`context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString())`;

Comment: I implemented this, and it works for some of my PDFs, but it seems that large ones are still displaying the gibberish. You have any idea what would cause this? I also tried adding the `Response.Clear()` before my switch and it does nothing.

Comment: does it work in IE? also try setting Response.Buffer = false.

Comment: I tried adding the buffer, and that did nothing. It does work in IE, but no other browsers. Thanks for your help so far, you have any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems to work for me. How large is the file.. Also, is it possible to try Response.TransmitFile and see?

Comment: I am using `BinaryWrite`. well after checking the file size I noticed that it doesn't do this on files less than 10MB in size. What would cause that? This has me even more perplexed on whats going on.

Comment: It sounds to me like FF/Chrome are ignoring the settings and still trying to set a buffer size of 10MB. Can you try Response.TransmitFile and see if there is any difference? Also see this link http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/IIS-ASP/33531854/response-buffer-limit-exceeded.aspx

Comment: ***Chrome and Android*** - *Android 4, Ice Cream Sandwich*. Example: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyFileName.ZIP";` will not work correctly because of the semicolon at the end. Any tests (and _summary_) for all Android versions ? Useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319389/streaming-mime-type-application-pdf-from-asp-app-fails-in-google-chrome `Google Chrome v12 release introduced a bug that triggers the problem you describe.
You can fix it by sending the Content-Length header` https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85549

Answer (score 0):

Has anything already been written to the Response stream?  Make sure to call `Response.Clear()` first.