# Generate pdf from bytes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have data in a byte array. Now I need to generate a PDF from the byte array in a browser when a button is clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: If the bytes are already in the form of a PDF document, you just need to set the headers correctly. This is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319389/streaming-mime-type-application-pdf-from-asp-app-fails-in-google-chrome

Comment: @DavidStratton that link to [whathaveyoutried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) should really be in the FAQ but then again, users posting questions like these never actually read the FAQ which is all the more ... well... downvotes speak for itself :)

Comment: hate them bloody userxxxxx hiding behind it and posting questions that just ensures the question the OP posted gets burned with fire!

Comment: I'm presuming that the byte array is not _actually_ a PDF document, but a series of numbers that you wish to render as a PDF? I recommend you add substantially more detail to your question, since it is likely to close in its present state!

Answer (score 7):

If that byte array *is* of `pdf` document then you may write bytes to the response buffer.

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
Resopnse.AddHeader("Content-Length",byteArray.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=sample.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the byte array is the binary representation of the PDF file, you should be able to set the correct response content type, and use the function `BinaryWrite` within the `Response` object.