# File download in ASP.NET MVC for Android

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, download

In my web site (in ASP.NET MVC); I need to display a PDF document in a new target. 
So I call an action. This is its code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
return File(fs, "application/pdf");
```

This works perfectly on my iPhone and my computer. But, on Android, the system try to download the file. That's not a problem for me, but the download fails all the time.
I've tried a lot of methods found on the net, without success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750012/android-browser-wont-download-pdf-file

Comment: I've already see this post. But I don't want to use action link, and my file is on the server, not on the the web site, so it don't have http adress.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had just to redirect on the PDF document to have a great display on iPhone and PC, and a correct download on Android. That was so simple!

My code:

```
return Redirect("http://myWebSite.com/documents/" + filename);
```