# File download Error - File downloading in html extension in android browser

Tags: c#, android, html

I am developing a website where users will download the attachment file from the website. The download functionality works fine in all desktop browsers but the download fails in android browser. The file downloading in ".htm" extension. you can find the download script (c#) below:

```
protected void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {

        LinkButton lnkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
        System.IO.FileInfo currentFIleInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(lnkButton.CommandArgument);

        if(currentFIleInfo.Exists) {
            Response.Clear();

            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" + lnkButton.Text.ToUpper() + """" ); 
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", currentFIleInfo.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
            Response.TransferFile(currentFIleInfo.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        MMHLogger.Error(ex);
    }

}
```

My aspx page looks like this

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3px">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href='<%# Eval("FileName", "../SiteContent/Uploads/{0}") %>' target="_blank">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ToolTip='<%# Eval("AlternativeText")%>' AlternateText='<%# Eval("AlternativeText")%>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FileName", "ImageThumbnailer.ashx?img=SiteContent/Uploads/{0}&size=72") %>' runat="server" BorderWidth="0" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("ImageName")%>
                                    <br />
                                    <%# Eval("ImageSize")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href='<%# Eval("FileName", "../SiteContent/Uploads/{0}") %>' target="_blank">View</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

I tried all the suggestions which listed in this blog : http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

But still the file download as in .htm extension in android browser.

Answer (score 0):

99% the error it's that you missed a "-" in MIME types.
Correct one is:

```
application/octet-stream
```

so basically android it's not detecting right type.

Comment: i changed the code but still the file is downloading in .htm extension

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674737/avoiding-content-type-issues-when-downloading-a-file-via-browser-on-android (last reply)

Comment: Thanks for ur rply i set the ContentType to application/octet-stream and the Content-Disposition filename value in double quotes and the Content-Disposition filename extension in UPPERCASE wat else i need to change in my code. im totally struck with this issue so pls help

Comment: I'm sorry but can't help directly for C# since I don't know it. You can give a try to set an explicit header Content Type (in addition or in alternative), so  Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "CONTENT=""application/octet-stream"");. Also, try to open htm that Android downloads, maybe you'll see something strange or string badly created!

Comment: hi i got solution for the download problem. i attached handler to solve the issue