# Docx file download

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to download .docx file. I would download using HTTP connection. But link is not direct link. So I am using intent to open url in browser. Consequently, browser will download it.

```
            String url = "http://dev.businessinfo.uz/document/template/download/link/528b07d162135";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
```

Problem is file is downloaded in bin file extention which can not be opened by doc viewer application.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your code, it happens when you use native browser. At that time it downloads file in ".bin" file format.

***However, if you use chrome then it will download in ".docx" file format.
I just tested your code. It works fine & I get that file in ".docx" file format. You need to download it via android google chrome browser.***

So I recommend you to open android mobile google chrome browser while calling implicit intent for opening/choosing browser for downloading file

Here I'm giving you link for the problem of automatic extension conversion while downloading file in native android browser.

Reference link :

[Avoiding content type issues when downloading a file via browser on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674737/avoiding-content-type-issues-when-downloading-a-file-via-browser-on-android)